# Elasticsearch: count query in _search script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-scripting

I'm trying to make a single query for updating the one field value in ES index.

I have a index `pages` which contain information about the pages (`id`, `name`, `time`, `parent_page_id`, `child_count` etc)

I can update the field `parent_page_id` with number of documents which have this page `id` as `parent_page_id`

I can update the field with default single value like:

```
PUT HOST_ADDRESS/pages/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "def child_count = 0; ctx._source.child_count = child_count;",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I'm trying with this code to get child count but its not working.

```
"source": "def child_count = 0; client.prepareSearch('pages').setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("parent_page_id", "ctx._source.id")).get().getTotal().getDocs().getCount(); ctx._source.child_count = child_count;",
    "lang": "painless"
```

My question is, how can i make a sub count-query in `script` to have a real child count in variable `child_count`

Comment: Are these child objects nested in the pages index?

Comment: no, the page index just every page as single object with parent page id

Comment: In that case, you'll need to join the data manually. It's not possible in ES to get data from an index and update another. So, you'll need to program that logic yourself. Joe's answer has a viable solution for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripting doesn't work like this — you cannot use java DSL in there. There's no concept of `client` or `QueryBuilders` etc in the [Painless contexts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-contexts.html).

As such, you'll need to obtain the counts *before* you proceed to update the doc(s) with a script.

Tip: scripts are reusable when you [store them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#script-stored-scripts):

```json
POST HOST_ADDRESS/_scripts/update_child_count
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.child_count = params.child_count"
  }
}
```

and then apply via the `id`:

```json
PUT HOST_ADDRESS/pages/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "id": "update_child_count",     <-- no need to write the Painless code again
    "params": {
      "child_count": 987
    }   
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "parent_page_id": 123
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @joe-sorocin for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, please upvote it. If it solved your issue, you can mark it as accepted.